# git push to remote repository "Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: git, ssh, repository, git-remote

I searched for a while but I can't find a solution to my Problem.

I have a Server I can connect to via ssh with the username `git` and a local git repository.
Now I want to push my local repository to a newly created one on the Server.

Here is what I did:

- created a git repository in `/home/git/test.git`
- initialized the repository as bare
- added the remote repository on the local machine
  `git remote add test ssh://git@serverIp:/home/git/test.git`
- now I executed the push command:
  `git push test master`

> I always get the

```
fatal: could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am working on a local windows 7 machine and want to upload to a linux server.
I can log in via ssh with the `git` user.
I also tried to do this as the `root` user(to get things to work once) with the same result.
I never get asked for the ssh `password`.

I really don't know what I am doing wrong.
Before you call this a duplicate, I searched a lot for this problem and none seemed to talk about the same problem.

update:

- "which git" returns /usr/bin/git
- PATH echo includes /usr/bin
- id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files are all set up and withput Passphrase
- ssh git@serverIp which git-receive-pack works too and returns /usr/bin/git-receive-pack
- ssh git@serverIp ls /home/git/test.git works
- all relevant directories are chmod 755
- git is owner of the repository
- auth.log file gets no new entries on tried push command
- GIT_TRACE=2 git push test master returns:

> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe' '-batch' 'git@serverIp' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/git/test.git'\''' fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: plink? Could you try it with openssh? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7697167/6309, http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html)

Comment: What the, What just happened? It works I just reinstalled Git choosing openssh instead of putty and it push without problem to the remote repository.

Comment: Right, I didn't see plink right away, but I always use openssh with my git installation. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Well they should remove plink from the list of choices if it reduces the functionality. Well thank you very much I used days on this Problem.

Comment: One reason might be the wrong ownership/mode for your home directory. I got `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/data/users/okopp`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this case, using openssh over putty was key.

---

Original answer (tips for debugging)

> I can log in via ssh with the `git` user.

That means this works:

```
ssh git@serverIp
```

You do have a `HOME` variable defined, and ssh public/private keys (`id_rsa` / `id_rsa.pub`) in `%HOME%/.ssh/`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509396/6309) suggests a different url:

```
git remote set-url test git@serverIp:/home/git/test.git
```

Make sure you did create your git repo as git (and not as root, when you created the git account, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15367016/6309)).
`ssh git@serverIp "which git"` should return the path of the git executable.

Check also that all parent directories have the relevant `x` (execute) bit set for the user `git` or the group `gitgroup`, running `ls -ld /home /home/git /home/git/test.git`.
Also, getting more info for a git command can be done with:

- `git push --verbose`
  or:
- `GIT_TRACE=2 git push test master`

If you have a private ssh key with a password, it would be best to first test those ssh commands with a private ssh key *not* password-protected, to see if the issue persists.
Or, you can keep that password-protected ssh key, but [double-check your `.bashrc` as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11918742/6309).

---

For any ssh connection issue (where git's password is needed), check:

- `/var/log/auth.log`,
- an [sshd debug session](https://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log)

---

In your case, since it works with `ssh git@serverIp` (interactive secure shell), but not with git (which opens a non-interactive secure shell), have a look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/git-users/fdxAkWOTTC8), which references [this one](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2008/Jun/msg00251.html):

> When ssh is started with a commandline, a non-interactive non-login shell is started.
>   However...`bash` does not use `$BASH_ENV` in this case, so setting it in `~/.ssh/environment` (e.g. to `/etc/profile`) doesn't help.
>   What bash does is source `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

Make sure that `/etc/profile` does define the [path for `git`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15532349/6309), since a [non-login account could be used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15651459/6309) (that seems to be the case here, since `ssh git@serverIp "which git"` worked, and `ssh git@serverIp "git --version"` should too).

But check also the right issue, and test a `chmod 755` on `/home`, `/home/git` and `/home/git/test.git`.

Comment: It turns out the `ssh://` url is [supported as well](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-SSH-Protocol), but it's specified wrong by the OP.  `ssh://git@serverIp:/home/git/test.git` is invalid because of the extra colon.  It should be `ssh://git@serverIp/test.git` or, as you suggest, `git@serverIP:/home/git/test.git` or `git@serverIp:test.git`.

Comment: i have the key set up in .ssh, I tried every version of url, i made sure git is the owner of test.git and test.git has execute bit set. verbose only give the additional "pushing to "url" message. Oh and i added the suggested script in the .bashrc

Comment: @user1090755 is your private ssh key password protected?

Comment: i entered a passphrase yes, but just now i created a new one with none. BTW "which git" asks for the git user password and then returns me the git executable path.

Comment: @user1090755 `ssh git@serverIP` should not ask you for `git`'s password, or that just means ssh keys aren't working properly. You can know more  by looking at `/var/log/auth.log`, or making one `sshd` debug session (http://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log)

Comment: You can also try using `GIT_TRACE=2 git push test master` might give useful information as well.

Comment: @user1090755 jszakmeister mentioned an additional debug advice, but forgot the `@` notification syntax. `GIT_TRACE=2 git push test master`

Comment: @VonC Thanks.  I forget the OP isn't necessarily notified when a comment is made.

Comment: okay so now ssh git@serverIp does not ask for a password anymore and the additional information reports this: trace: built-in: git 'push' 'test' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe' '-batch' 'git@serverIp' 'git-receive-pack '\''/home/git/test.git'\'''
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @user1090755 it could be because git would use a non-login account, which might not have the right to access your git repo. see my edit.

Comment: hmm so i checked /etc/profile and PATH includes /usr/bin with "which git" returning /usr/bin/git. I also tried editing the other three files mentioned in your source to no avail. Oh and chmod 755 for all three directories also changed nothing

Comment: @user1090755 and a `ssh git@serverIp which git-receive-pack` works too?

Comment: @user1090755 then it should be a right access issue. Does this work? `ssh git@serverIp ls /home/git/test.git` (replace `test.git` with your bare repo directory)

Comment: @user1090755 can you clone it first, make a commit locally and push it? Does a `git clone ssh://git@serverIP:/home/git/test.git` work?

Comment: no i can't clone reports the same fatal Error as pushing to it

Comment: @user1090755 ok, but what does return `ssh git@serverIp echo \$PATH` though?

Comment: I already did that and it just returns what is specified in the profile /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/x11:/usr/games

Comment: @user1090755 so a non-interactive session has the right path and access rights... but it still fails? Frustrating! Beside some kind of firewall/anti-virus issue, I am a bit at a loss. Cloning directly on the server works, right?

Comment: cloning on the Server works just get a warning that i seem to have cloned an empty repository

Comment: @user1090755 when cloning form the client (windows 7), any clue in the `/var/log/auth.log` file (sshd logs)? I'll be back in 90 minutes for more suport

Answer (score 8):

You can also check your SSH identities by doing:

```
$ ssh-add -L
```

I had a similar problem. There was a wrong key in my identities, don't remember why.
I just delete all my identities (maybe you will need to add keys again):

```
$ ssh-add -D
```

Then I did push/pull without problems.

Comment: Great answer..... you saved my time...I was getting pissed off since last one hour...tried all other stuff..

Answer (score 7):

I personally had 2 different issues with this:

1. `plink` (which is used by git on Windows) does not accept `id_rsa` private key as it is in OpenSSH 2 format => I had to convert it (using `puttygen`) to PuTTY own `.ppk` format and attach via Git Extensions "`Remotes`" dialog
2. I specified the path to git folder wrongly, 'cause my ssh session was chrooted (It might be wrong word) and I specified that what was my FTP "`root`" as "`/`", while it was "`/home/www/username/`" instead.

I understood all this, using `GIT TRACE=2` as described above and also by using `procmon` to determine the exact command-line for `plink` and then playing with it, adding "`-v`" option ("verbose").

Answer (score 0):

Set GIT_SSH environment variable to the full path of `TortoisePlink.exe` (you may have to download TortoiseGit for this) instead of PuTTY's `plink.exe`. This will allow for popup dialog window to prompt for things, i.e., confirm fingerprint, or enter password. If you use `plink.exe` through Git, you cannot type in responses to plink.exe prompts, which if there are any prompts will cause the fatal error you saw.